# asssign type as ChartType to angular google chart

Tags: angular

I trying to add a google chart to my angular website using google chart.
I've install the npm package and add it to the import in app mudule. When I try in my code, it doesn't recognise the given type as a chartType. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

here's the code :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  templateUrl: './results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results.component.scss']
})
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {

  public selectedOption = 1

  chart = {
    title: "",
    type: 'LineChart',
    data: [
      ["Jan",  7.0],
      ["Feb",  6.9],
      ["Mar",  9.5],
      ["Apr",  14.5],
      ["May",  18.2],
      ["Jun",  21.5],
      ["Jul",  25.2],
      ["Aug",  26.5],
      ["Sep",  23.3],
      ["Oct",  18.3],
      ["Nov",  13.9],
      ["Dec",  9.6]
    ],
    columnNames :["Month", "result"],
    options: {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Month'
        },
        vAxis:{
          title: 'result'
        }
    }
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


}
```

```html
...
  <google-chart [title]="chart.title" [type]="chart.type" [data]="chart.data" [columns]="chart.columnNames" [options]="chart.options"></google-chart>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChartType is an enum not a string so it must be specified as ChartType. See the [docs](https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts#type) and the [source code](https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts/blob/master/libs/angular-google-charts/src/lib/models/chart-type.model.ts)

```
import { ChartType } from 'angular-google-charts';

...

chartType: ChartType = 'LineChart'
```

or you can cast the type in your object.

```
chart = {
      ...
      type: 'LineChart' as ChartType,
      ...
}
```